# Equations of the union of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, systems-of-equations, intersection-theory

Say I have two sets

$$A = \big\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n : f(x)=0, g(x)=0 \big\} \, , \\
B = \big\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n : h(x)=0, j(x)=0 \big\} \, , $$

described by some implicit equations. How can I describe the union $A \cup B$ in terms of implicit equations? I guess, just like the intersection $A \cap B$ is described by the union of the equations, the union must be described by the $intersection$ of the equations. But how do you actually compute this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=V(f)\cap V(g)$ and $B=V(h)\cap V(j)$ where $V(f)=\{x:f(x)=0\}$ etc.
Therefore
\begin{align}
A\cup B&=(V(f)\cap V(g))\cup(V(h)\cap V(j))\\
&=(V(f)\cup V(h))\cap (V(f)\cup V(j))\cap
(V(g)\cup V(h))\cap (V(g)\cup V(j)).
\end{align}
But $V(f)\cup V(h)=V(fh)$ etc., so
$$A\cup V(fh)\cap V(fj)\cap V(gh)\cap V(gj),$$
the locus of vanishing of the four functions $fh$, $fj$, $gh$, $gj$.